# Look up aggregate join collections and with group aggregate - Mongo C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb

I'm trying to get name of city and number of employees that live in it. but i didn't reached what I want.I'm using mongo db with .net core and I have the following classes:

Employee:

```
public class Employee {
public string FirstName {get;set;}
public string LastName {get;set;}
public string cityId {get;set;}
....
}
```

City:

```
public class City {
public string CityId {get;set;}
public string CityName {get;set}
....
}
```

I know I can follow another structure but this what I have right now. I know it's wrong and that why I'm asking for a help.

```
var result = city.Aggregate().Lookup<City,Employee,cityId,Employee>.Group(x => new { x.Key.CityName, x.Key.Count()}).ToList()
```

I prefer to use Lookup and Group aggregate instead of other ways.

Answer (score 0):

this will get the result you want. the `.AsQueryable()` interface also targets the aggregation framework, so there's no performance difference between this and `.Aggregate()` afaik.

```cs
    var result = employeeCollection.AsQueryable()
                   .GroupBy(e => e.cityId)
                   .Select(g => new { employeeCount = g.Count(), cityId = g.Key })
                   .Join(cityCollection.AsQueryable(),
                         x => x.cityId,
                         c => c.CityId,
                         (x, c) => new { x.employeeCount, c.CityName })
                   .ToList();
```

test program:

```js
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;
using MongoDB.Entities;
using MongoDB.Entities.Core;
using System.Linq;

namespace StackOverFlow
{
    public class Employee : Entity
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string CityID { get; set; }
    }

    public class City : Entity
    {
        public string CityName { get; set; }
    }

    public static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            new DB("test");

            var ny = new City { CityName = "New York" };
            var la = new City { CityName = "Los Angeles" };
            new[] { la, ny }.Save();

            new[] {
                new Employee { FirstName = "NY One", CityID = ny.ID},
                new Employee { FirstName = "NY Two", CityID = ny.ID},
                new Employee { FirstName = "LA One", CityID = la.ID},
                new Employee { FirstName = "LA Two", CityID = la.ID},
            }.Save();

            var result = DB.Queryable<Employee>()
                           .GroupBy(e => e.CityID)
                           .Select(g => new { employeeCount = g.Count(), cityID = g.Key })
                           .Join(DB.Queryable<City>(),
                                 x => x.cityID,
                                 c => c.ID,
                                 (x, c) => new { x.employeeCount, c.CityName })
                           .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```